# How to filter emails by subject containing a word?

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters, google-workspace-for-business, gmail-search

I want to filter all emails with subjects containing a word.

So far I tried `subject:(has: abc)` but it doesn't work.

---

It works for me in personal free account, but doesn't work in gsuite corporate account.

Comment: I asked a similar question about the use of the AND condition here: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/168017/how-to-use-and-condition-is-gmail-filter

Comment: This was bumped by Community user seven times. I’m voting to close this question because, as of October 30, 2023, it's not reproducible. I created a filter on my Google Workspace account and made a test sending an email from another account. It worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering what's wrong with a simple query like this?

```
subject:abc
```

From my testing, it returns all emails with titles containing `abc` *as a word*. It does *not* return emails with titles like `abcd`.

Comment: It works for me in personal free account, but doesn't work in gsuite corporate account.

Comment: Wow!  I didn't know that.  I just tested and confirmed.  I am shocked that the behavior is different.  Good grief does everything need to be an apps script?

Answer (score -1):

Can't you just use the dialog box for creating filters?
[image: dialog box]