# How to use AND condition is gmail filter

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters, email-bounces

I'm sending a lot of email and would like to filter out bounced emails from my inbox.

I'm trying to create a Gmail filter that filters out all messages with a subject that contains certain text AND one of two possible strings in its content.

Currently, it says:

```
from:(my@email.com) ("Product Designer for the Future of Knowledge Management?" AND ("Your message wasn't delivered to" OR "Message blocked"))
```

Unfortunately the AND operator does not seem to work.

This [article](https://hiverhq.com/blog/gmail-filters) said:

> AND: By default, Google combines all search terms with an invisible AND operator. For example, searching for Dunder Mifflin finds all emails containing the words Dunder and Mifflin.

This question is similar to the existing question "[How to filter emails by subject containing a word](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/160666/how-to-filter-emails-by-subject-containing-a-word)?"

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`from:(my@email.com) subject:(Product Designer for the future of Knowledge Management) {"Your message wasn't delivered to" "Message blocked"}`